# Como criar apps na aplicação Django, dentro de um conteiner, com a utlização do Docker Compose? Não sei porque não consigo

Tags: django, aplicação-web, docker

Olá, tenho uma dúvida sobre Django com Docker compose . Gostaria de saber como faz para criar apps na aplicação Django (estou usando VSCode) já dentro do container .
Tenho a pasta do projeto principal, ao iniciar o container abre normal na porta que foi definida para o Django.
Consigo executar o comando migrate e makemigrations com   : docker-compose run web python manage.py migrate  e  docker-compose run web python manage.py makemigrations , e executa normal.

Consigo executar a porta para abrir no navegador, tanto pelo Docker hub como se executar o comando  docker-compose run web python manage.py runserver

Mas gostaria de saber como faço para criar apps e então seguir com a minha aplicação , pois quando executo  :
docker-compose run web python manage.py startapp nomedoapp
não funciona ...
Ele carrega , não acontece, não aparece nenhuma pasta e volta pedindo para digitar novo comando .. Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Aparece  "creating....done" ..mas não cria nada , não aparece nada , como deveria aparecer se estivesse fora do container

Já tentei executar dentro da venv como fora, e o resultado é o mesmo.

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaoSK.png)

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N615O.png)

Answer (score -2):

Você pode entrar dentro do container que contém sua aplicação django, criar o seu app e dps sair.

```
> docker-compose exec -it web /bin/bash
```

A partir daqui você estará dentro do seu container web, em seguida crie seu app django

```
> python manage.py startapp app_name
```